# Can I generate a service SOAP into a JAR in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

I have a project with spring boot, this project exposes a web service SOAP. The project with embedded tomcat in local server runs without problem, in the next image you can see the consume:

[consume service good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMR4L.png)

But I tried to deploy the JAR file into a Q.A server, this server cointais a  embedded tomcat, but the consume fail:

[consume fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYpru.jpg)

- it is possible to generate a JAR with the SOAP service? or I need to
  packaging the project into a WAR file?
- This project can run into a embedded tomcat? or I need to install a
  dedicated server?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi. Did you try to exclude embedded tomcat when you create jar for deploying?

Comment: To deploy you need a war. But if it is running by itself, why even bother with deploying to tomcat?